# How to build SDL libraries for Android

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, ffmpeg, sdl

I am planning to use SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer) to display video output in my Android application that uses ffmpeg libraries. I have downloaded the sources from http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php and built (./configure, make & make install) on my Ubuntu. But when I use these .so files the Android ndk-build complains that "Could not read symbols. File in wrong Format".

Can I use the .so files that are built on Ubuntu on Android or do I need to build the SDL for Android in a different way?

Comment: You will need to build them using the [ndk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) - Android devices typically use arm processors and your x86 .so-file is not compatible.

Comment: @Jens thank you for clarifying. Can you please describe how I can build SDL using ndk? I tried modifying the configuration file with target type but ran into build errors. Alternatively is there any place where I can download the already compiled libSDL.so files?

Comment: Have you checked out the [readme](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/README.android) for libsdl regarding Android?

Comment: @Jens Thank you, I have read the readme file and tried many things but couldn't get it to link successfully. So in the end I have gone with OpenGL and now the display works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the `README.android`

you need to add in your jni folder a symbolic link to the `SDL` folder, after in your `jni/src/Android.mk` be sure you have these lines

```
SDL_PATH := ../SDL

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include

# Add your application source files here...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.cpp \
    main.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This way the .so of SDL will be compiled for your target (certainly ARM cpu) along with your project, and automatically include in the final .apk

when you do ./configure && make && make install, you're actually building the .so for your computer's CPU (certainly for x86 / x86_64)